# sphinx sort with sql_attr_str2ordinal at textual unicode field

Tags: sphinx

i'm using sql_attr_str2ordinal for textual field, so i can do sort. I have read the documentation that explains how it works.(using the bytes etc...) if i understand that correct, it is impossible to sort textual field by locale? How it's possible to achive that?

Sorting example(look for č letter):
wrong sort:
a
b
c
d
e
.
.
.
z
č

right sort:
a
b
c
č
d
e
.
.
.
z

From docs:

> Ideally the strings should be sorted differently, depending on the
>   encoding and locale. For instance, if the strings are known to be
>   Russian text in KOI8R encoding, sorting the bytes 0xE0, 0xE1, and 0xE2
>   should produce 0xE1, 0xE2 and 0xE0, because in KOI8R value 0xE0
>   encodes a character that is (noticeably) after characters encoded by
>   0xE1 and 0xE2. Unfortunately, Sphinx does not support that at the
>   moment and will simply sort the strings bytewise.

Comment: Seems, that it couldn't be done in that way as sphinx is sorting strings bytewise and, for example, `č` has much bigger HEX value that `c`

Answer (score 1):

You can now use string attributes for sorting.

There is collation settings to effect this. 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#collations

the documentation in str2ordinal hasnt been updated to note it.

Comment: This will be the answer. Thx barryhunter